# What is this feature of floating point?

Tags: d, point, floating

**Real Close to the Machine: Floating Point in D**

https://dlang.org/articles/d-floating-point.html

says

> Useful relations for a floating point type F, where x and y are of type F
>
> ...
>
> - x>0 if and only if 1/(1/x) > 0; x<0 if and only if 1/(1/x) < 0.

what is the meaning of this sentence?

Answer (score 5):

In the text you're quoting, we're looking at how the representation is symmetric around 1, and that the rounding doesn't break this. That is, for any number `0 < x < 1`, there's a corresponding number `1 < y < ∞`, such that `y = 1/x` and `1/y = x`. That's the first half - the second is simply the same for negative numbers: `0 > x > -1` and `-1 > y > -∞`.

It may not be immediately obvious how this can be a problem, but consider `x = 3`. 
`y` must then be `1/3 = 0.333...`. With a limited precision of 3 decimal digits, `1/y` would then be `3.003003003...`. [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) defines how this should work, and says that the rounding should ensure `1/(1/x)` should be equal to `x`, and thus that the result should be `3`, even if there are rounding errors in both `1/x` and `1/y` - they should cancel each other out.

Older floating-point systems weren't as well-behaved as IEEE 754. I'm not sure if any of them weren't symmetric around 1, but that's certainly within the realm of possibility.